# Leaflet Map moves to opened popups when zooming in (React-leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, javascript

i wanted to open the popup Markers when the MapZoom is at a  certain value ,i got the
mapZoom   using the map.getZoom() on the zoomend Event   , a  state is set for the MapZoom  when the user scrolls in/out

```js
const map = useMapEvents({

zoomend(e){
setZoom(map.getZoom())   
}
   
}
  })
```

, when  Map Zoom is >12 popups should open and vice versa now they're opened anyways since i am Calling the  openPopup() [image: here is a screenshot],

```js
useEffect(()=>{
if(popupRef.current!==undefined&&zoom>12){
// regardless of the zoom value the popups stay open Anyways which is another Problem 
// it's suppose to only open when the zoom is >12 but that's not the Case 
   console.log(zoom)
   popupRef.current.openPopup()   
 
 }
},[props])
```

i Encountred an issue when the user ZoomsIn the map drifts towards the popup now i've played a bit with my Code  when i disabled the Zoom state this behaviour vanished but now i can't track my Zoom value Anymore
how do i prevent the Map from moving at my popupMarker when i zoomIn  using MouseScrollWheel?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my Problem `Encountred an issue when the user ZoomIn the map drifts towards the popup`  i set the AutoPan prop to False as i am using react-leaflet and it worked just fine   i'll keep this Post for Reference  if anyone faces the same Problem in the Future